# How to stream several different pygame windows at the same time?

Tags: python3, ffmpeg, streaming, emulation, rtmp

I am trying to do a comment driven live stream on several platforms at the same time. I am using pygame for the visualization by constantly saving an image of the game window using GTK and GDK, then loading the image using pygame and displaying it with other displays. However, I need to be able to stream several pygame windows to different sites. I originally tried just streaming a simple java processing window with sound on windows using ffmpeg, but I was having trouble because of sound drivers and microphones, and it would just not work.

I then tried using visual boxes running Ubuntu on on the same computer. Ubuntu has pulse which allows me to customize sound. I had I separate pygame window in each emulator that was streamed using ffmpeg from inside. However, I was unable to draw anything to pygame as the streaming and the visual boxes used all of the computer resources. I then saw that visual box would run faster emulating the OS it was run on. So I got my friend's old computer and changed the OS to Ubuntu and tried again. However it was still too slow.

I then tried removing the visual boxes entirely and having 3 pygame windows on OS. However, I then realized that ffmpeg (the rtmp stream aplication I was using) didn't have the option to stream specific windows on linux like it did with windows OS on my first try. It only had the option to stream specific pixel areas.

- How can I stream several pygame windows at the same time?
- Are there much faster, better, and low-resource Ubuntu emulator alternatives?
- Are there rtmp streaming applications that would allow for stream several windows at once? Something to do with workspaces or extra displays that I missed in my research?
- Are there other Linux versions that allow for this? Or will I be forced to create a new distro?

I would like the most computer resources possible, so the less resources the alternative uses, the better. I also need to be able to start and configure everything from terminal.

Comment: SimpleScreenRecorder allows you to record any OpenGL window: https://i.imgur.com/LUKFg2D.png

Comment: The window is in Pygame. I really don't want to change that as I have most of the stream finished. Also I need to be able to start and configure the stream from terminal. I can't find a terminal API. The streaming is also still experimental, which I have learned to stay away from, due to massive overhauls and changes. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: PyGame actually uses OpenGL under the hood as far as I know, so you can keep using your existing PyGame code

Comment: That is good to know. However, there are still the other issues though.